# TCP/IP: Своя реализация Heartbeat: Можно ли упростить алгоритм, и как?

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, tcp-ip, сокеты

Дано:
- интернет и требование к системе работать 24/7, каждый день обрывы сети у провайдера и т.п.
- сервер должен регулярно проверять связь, чтобы быстро обнаружить обрыв и убрать клиента из списка доступных
- клиент должен регулярно проверять связь, чтобы быстро обнаружить обрыв и начать попытки подключиться к серверу повторно

Я не долго думая решил проблему "в лоб" - сделал два раздельных "контура" heartbeatов, один работает для клиента, другой для сервера.
Если выбросить всю остальную логику, то схема получилась такой (сверху - хронология, снизу - алгоритм клиента и алгоритм сервера):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но что получается? Каждые N секунд (на картинке sleep не показан, но он есть и там и там) по каналу отправляется четыре пакета - многовато.
Да и алгоритм получился довольно запутанный.

Можно ли как-то упростить схему, ограничившись лишь двумя пакетами?

Comment: на heartbeat не нужен ответ

Comment: ...и если у вас кроме heartbeat что-то регулярно передается по каналу, то и сам heartbeat не нужен, если в последние N секунд по каналу что-то передавалось: вы можете отсчитывать время для передачи следуещего heartbeat не со времени предыдущего, а со времени с последней успешной передачи данных, в результате чего heartbeat у вас будет посылаться только когда по каналу никто не общался N секунд. А это значит, что и канал, и машина не загружены, и ничего страшного в том, чтобы подзагрузить их, нет.

Comment: Можно ограничится активностью только с одной стороны, например, сервера. Т.о. клиент, получив пакет от сервера убеждается, что тот жив, а сервер в свою очередь получая response понимает, что клиент жив. Кстати, вам наверное известно, что по tcp-соединению помимо основного потока можно независимо передавать поток, так называемых, out-of-band (Urgent) data (флаг `MSG_OOB` в вызовах `send()` и `recv()`, подробнее в [man 7 tcp](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp)), что, возможно, более удобно для реализации heartbeat, поскольку в этом случае данные heartbeat не будут перемешиваться с основным обменом

Comment: @Etki "на heartbeat не нужен ответ" Да? Тогда как же мне понять, что с соединением все в порядке, и отправить следующий heartbeat? Посмотрел стандартный keepalive, в нем тоже вроде что-то вроде ответа есть.................  "и если у вас кроме heartbeat что-то регулярно передается по каналу" у меня неделями может ничего не передаваться по каналу

Comment: @avp Не забывайте что обрыв может случиться в любой момент, поэтому изначально каждая из сторон должна сделать send()  - "пусковой" heartbeat - потом recv(), а значит и далее тоже так, см. другой мой вопрос, я сейчас другим занят, я подумаю но по-моему только с одной нереально............ MSG_OOB на винде поддерживается? а яблоки?

Comment: Нет. Просто каждая из сторон должна сразу установить таймаут на *получение данных heartbeat* и переустанавливать его по получению данных. Клиент получает запрос, сервер ответ. Получил, переустановил таймаут. Про винду и яблоки врать не буду, гуглите. По идее должен быть.

Comment: Heartbeat отправляется, если по каналу N времени ничего не отправлялось. Ответы - это тупо дублирование этого функционала.

Comment: heartbeat совсем не нужен для того, что бы обнаружить "пропажу" второй стороны соединения, если Вы только не желаете усложнить себе задачу. В качестве рабочего примера можете посмотреть например протокол SMPP, в частности сообщение Enquire_link. Больше не припомню нигде ничего подобного хербиту.

Comment: @Sergey O_0 а keepalive не хербит что ли? а он кругом, хоть в удал. рабстолах, что в мессенджерах. но я хочу свой хербит, чтобы весь процесс контролировать самому и минимально зависеть от платформы - на перспективу

Comment: @KG В вопросе речь про свою реализацию, А keepalive реализовывать не надо, его надо просто включить, если он поддерживается в системе. Вот немного о том как он работает http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html И keepalive не обязательная опция, т.е. её может не быть в системе в принципе (хотя теперь-то наверняка везде есть)

Comment: @Sergey я знаю, что это такое и как он работает, в том-то и дело, что может не быть